# Retrieve out of office Status using EWS 2.0

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

Is there any way to check Out Of Office status of a person using EWS 2.0 Api. I tried using "OofSettings" class to retrieve the Out Of Office status. It works fine if I check my own out of office status but says Access is denied when I try to pass someone else's email address. Here is the code I used.

```
OofSettings userOOFSettings = service.GetUserOofSettings("sneh.tekriwal@intel.com");
//Now to check out of office status
Console.WriteLine(userOOFSettings.State); //Works fine when I check OOO status for my own email id
```

But when I change the email address and use any of my colleagues, it gives me access is denied. 
Is there any way around this as, I cannot get impersonation on other mailbox.
Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Out of Office for another mailbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795929/how-to-get-out-of-office-for-another-mailbox)

Comment: There was no accepted answer to that question. So I thought to ask it again. :( Also none of the answer solve my question.

Comment: From the answer provided, it would seem that you need to use impersonation to do this.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question impersonation is not a choice for me, as I won't be allowed permissions on mailboxes of other users in my organisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Exchange 2010 or later then you can get the OOF status using the OOF mailtip which doesn't require access to the target mailbox see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devmsg/archive/2014/06/03/ews-how-to-retrieve-the-oof-out-of-facility-settings-message-using-ews-for-an-exchange-user.aspx for a sample

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thanks, I now can get the xml string which contains the out of office reply. :)